# Cypress Expected to find element: '.checkbox_0.0', but never found it

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a problem with cypress not being able to find a checkbox on the page.

This checkbox is rendered after cypress click on a button, but even if the checkbox is visible on the page cypress gives an error:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.checkbox_0.0', but never found it.
```

```js
it('add a sibling"', () => {
  //click the button:
  cy.pause();
  cy.get('#ciccia').click({ force: true });

  //click the checkbox that has just appeared:
  cy.get('.checkbox_0.0').click({ force: true });
});
```

[image]

even if the checkbox_0.0 is present as you can see in the image

what can I do to get that checkbox?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `cy.get('input.checkbox_0.0').should('be.visible').click({ force: true })`

Comment: I've tried it now and still: CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: 'input.checkbox_0.0', but never found it. 
I guess that since the "get" fails then it can't do the should() ?

Comment: You can add a bit of timeout specific to this get  `cy.get('input.checkbox_0.0', {timeout: 10000}).should('be.visible').click({ force: true })`

Comment: tried but doesn't work,  I dont think it's a problem of time because the checkbox appears in a sec, but for some reason it seems that Cypress can get only the elements present in the page when page first loaded..I have no clues on how to solve it

Comment: Did you try using Cypress's Selector Playground button within the test runner? I'm curious to see if it suggests a different selector.

Comment: Could you provide an example code that can repro your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience (sorry, it would be ideal to see the source code too), but this could be due to the **element being inside an iframe**. At this stage, Cypress does not seem to support elements residing inside `iframe` with this Github issue still open: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136

From a few workarounds on the link above, this resolved my issue:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('iframe', { prevSubject: 'element' }, $iframe => {
    return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
        $iframe.on('load', () => {
            resolve($iframe.contents().find('body'));
        });
    });
});
// for <iframe id="foo" src="bar.html"></iframe>
cy.get('#foo').iframe().find('.checkbox_0.0').click({ force: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this method if elements is inside iframe:

```
getIframeDocument = () => {
        return cy.get('object').its('0.contentDocument').its('body').then(cy.wrap)
    }
```

And then call this method like :

```
this.getIframeDocument().find("yourlocater").click();
```